# How to convert a dictionary object to Node in py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a dictionary object like the following

```
node_info = {'id':'2344','name':'xyz'}
```

I want to convert it to py2neo Node so that it can be created using `graph.create()`. `Node.cast()` is no longer supported. Any other way

Comment: Couldn't you use `Node(**node_info)`? *(See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761 if this syntax is unfamiliar.)*

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition for py2neo v4.0's [Node class](https://py2neo.org/v4/data.html#py2neo.data.Node):

`class py2neo.data.Node(*labels, **properties)`

which means you can pass any number of labels:

`Node("Person", "Professor")`

and any number of labelled/named properties:

`Node(id=10, name="Long John Silver")`

---

#### Answering your question

You can achieve the above with either a list (for labels) and dict (for named properties):

```py
labels = ["Person", "Professor"]
props  = {"id": 10, "name": "Long John Silver"}
print(Node(*labels, **props))
```

will yield:

`(:Person:Professor {id: 10, name: 'Long John Silver'})`

This is because of Python's `*args` and `**kwargs` in python [Geeks4Geeks ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)